# What is the optimal linear algebraic method to find: $\min_N C D^{N-2} A $?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, optimization

### Question

What is the linear algebra way to minimise the below expression:

$$ \min_N C D^{N-2} A = ?$$

where,

$$D_{jk} = \begin{cases} 
      0 & j < k \\
      (-1)^k & j=0 \\
      (-1)^{j-k} \text{ }{ }^j C_k & \text{else}
   \end{cases}
$$

Or explicitly:

$$ D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 &\dots  \\
    0       & 1 & -2  & 3 & -4 & \dots \\
    0       & 0 & 1 & -3 & 6 & \dots \\
    \vdots \\
    0       & 0 &  \dots &  & &1   &
\end{pmatrix}$$

and $A = (a_0, a_1, \dots)^T$ where $a_i(a_i -1) = 0$, beyond an arbitrary $m$ with $m<n$ we have $a_n = 0$ and $C = (1,0,0,\dots)$ and $N \geq 0$

### Motivation (Number theoretic way to minimize)

I had the following idea of using digits as vectors. Let us have say I have a three digit number $a$ in the basis $\lambda$:

$$ a = a_0 + a_1 \lambda + a_2 \lambda^2$$

Now, we want to convert $\lambda$ coefficients to $\lambda+1$ coefficients:

$$ a = a_0 -a_1 +a_2 + (a_1 - 2a_2) (\lambda +1) + a_2(\lambda +1)^2 $$

We note if $a_0 -a_1 +a_2$ is divisible by $\lambda+1$ then so is $a$. And since we are only interested checking if the number is divisible, we introduce the divisibility matrix $D$ (for $3$ digits):

$$
(\lambda+1) |a   \implies (\lambda+ 1)|
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & -1 & 1  \\
    0       & 1 & -2 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a_0 \\
    a_1 \\
    a_2
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Since this number is in basis $\lambda + 1$ then trivially,

$$
(\lambda+1) |a   \implies 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & -1 & 1  \\
    0       & 1 & -2 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a_0 \\
    a_1 \\
    a_2
\end{pmatrix} = 0 
$$

Similarly  if the $a$ is divisible by $\lambda+2$

$$
(\lambda+2) | a \implies 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & -1 & 1  \\
    0       & 1 & -2 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2
\begin{pmatrix}
    a_0 \\
    a_1 \\
    a_2
\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

One can calculate the [general form of this matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593305/what-is-the-general-n-times-n-form-of-the-divisibility-matrix)  $D$ to find:

$$D_{jk} = \begin{cases} 
      0 & j < k \\
      (-1)^k & j=0 \\
      (-1)^{j-k} \text{ }{ }^j C_k & \text{else}
   \end{cases}
$$

To write it some terms explicitly:

$$ D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 &\dots  \\
    0       & 1 & -2  & 3 & -4 & \dots \\
    0       & 0 & 1 & -3 & 6 & \dots \\
    \vdots \\
    0       & 0 &  \dots &  & &1   &
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let $A = (a_0, a_1, \dots)^T$, $C = (1,0,0,\dots)$ and $\lambda = 2$ then

$$ \min_N C D^{N-2} A = 0$$

The solutions of $N$ which minimise $C D^{N-2} A$ are factors of $a$

### Example

Consider $6$ in binary $110$. Then, $A= (0,1,1,0,0, \dots)^T$

And indeed for $N= 2,3$

$$ C D^{N-2} A = 0$$